# jQuery layout plug-in - create layout dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-layout

I'm using jQuery UI Layout Plug-in (http://layout.jquery-dev.net/). I need to load a layout on a modal window depending on certain parameters. So on-event I do something like:

```
$('<div id="container"><div class="ui-layout-west"> <div class="left-panel"><div class="fuelux">Somthing here</div> </div> </div> <div class="ui-layout-center">Something else here </div></div>').layout();
```

I have no idea why it does not build the layout. Does the plug-in support something like that?..

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Sure, that should work. However, are you actually adding the content to the page? I'd expect them to need to be part of the dom before you call layout.

Comment: Yes, I'm adding the content to the modal. So I guess I have to create the dialog first, then lookup for #content and call layout() ?

Comment: Basically, yes. See @cfs's answer and the comment.

Comment: Thanks @cfs. 
This helped me with the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/YGT5p/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add your HTML to the DOM first, then initialize the layout. In the example below, I'm adding the container to the `body`, but you could add it to any element in the DOM:

```
$('<div id="container"><div class="ui-layout-west"> <div class="left-panel"><div class="fuelux">Somthing here</div> </div> </div> <div class="ui-layout-center">Something else here </div></div>').appendTo('body').layout();
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YGT5p/1)

Comment: Note, you could also just do `$('<div id="container"><div class="ui-layout-west"> <div class="left-panel"><div class="fuelux">Somthing here</div> </div> </div> <div class="ui-layout-center">Something else here </div></div>').appendTo('body').layout()`

Comment: Nice... I wasn't sure what appendTo would be returning; but you're right, I'll update to save the unnecessary lookup

Comment: It seems to work.. partially.. bacause now all my layout disappears.

$('<div title="Column expression"><div></div></div>').append($expressionEditor).appendTo('body').dialog({
                        
                        modal: true,                        
                        buttons: {
                            ....
                        },
                        open: function (event, ui) {
                            $(this).find('#container').layout();                            
                        }
                    });

Comment: do you have other layouts on the page that are created before this one?

Comment: Yes, I do have other layouts. The problem is that I want to show this new layout in a modal dialog.

Comment: Hmm... I'm able to add another layout dynamically after creating a layout: http://jsfiddle.net/YGT5p/2/ Could you post a jsFiddle that replicates what you're seeing?

Comment: Sure, let me modify yours adding the dialog call.. Thanks!

Comment: Here is. http://jsfiddle.net/YGT5p/3/
When you pause it in the open event before the layout call you can see that the content of the dialog is displayed. Once the layout is called the content kinda disappears.

Comment: The layout is being rendered but the height is 0. You'll need to explicitly set a height for `.container2` and then you will see it: http://jsfiddle.net/YGT5p/4/